# convert each row of dataframe to a list of tuples with column name and value as tuple

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, time-series, tuples

I am trying to efficiently find a way to create a list of tuple for each row of the dataframe including the index. so what i am trying to do is basically for row1 create a list of tuple like [( index , array [2018-04-09 00:00:00 ] ) , ('A' , array [1] ) , ('B' , array [a] )] similarly a different list of tuple for row2 ,row3 and so on.

```
       index              A  B                 
     2018-04-09 00:00:00  1  a  
     2018-04-09 00:20:00  2  b  
     2018-04-09 00:40:00  3  c  
     2018-04-09 01:00:00  4  d
```

I tried to do something like below:-

```
 for index,row in df.iterrows():
     print(list(row.itertuples(index=False)))
```

This gives me an error 'Series' object has no attribute 'itertuples'.

One way i can do is iterate over each row and individually create tuple for each column value and the add them to a list, but what i want to do is write precise and elegant code for it.

Thanks